# How to define a multivariate state space model with SARIMAX

Tags: statsmodels, kalman-filter, state-space, multivariate-time-series, sarimax

I want to create a state space with a `mutivariate` endog data frame:

```
data_augmented = pd.DataFrame({'x' : endog, 'Y_t_1': Y_t_1})
```

but when I run the SARIMAX command:

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data_augmented, order=(1,1,1))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: SARIMAX models require univariate `endog`. Got shape (300, 2).
```

data_augmented has two states/variables (300, 2). I was expecting the function to create the multivariate stace space. Ultimately, I want the Kalman Filter to use the multivariate state space model to estimate unobservable states